# timeout parameter does not make any effect on Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I want user to wait for specified time(4seconds) to get connected to server. If it cannot connect within the specified time period, application should get closed.

Here is what I have coded:

```
var downloadDataReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({timeout :4000});
downloadDataReq.onload = function() { //some code }
downloadDataReq.onerror = function(event) { //some code }
var urlToDownloadData = 'http://www.google.com';
downloadDataReq.open("POST", urlToDownloadData);
downloadDataReq.send();
```

The Problem is that app waits for fix time (timeout parameter does not effect at all).

P.S.: making an app for android using Titanium.

Comment: What happens when you do downloadDataReq.setTimeout(4000); ?

Comment: ok, doing downloadDataReq.setTimeout(4000); after downloadDataReq.open("POST", urlToDownloadData); works....i think there is some issue with timeout parameter in constructor of Titanium.Network.HTTPClient... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use method like this:

```
downloadDataReq.setTimeout(4000);
```

Comment: doing downloadDataReq.setTimeout(4000); after downloadDataReq.open("POST", urlToDownloadData); works....i think there is some issue with timeout parameter in constructor of Titanium.Network.HTTPClient

Answer (score 0):

For me, timeout on HTTP requests aren't working as it should. I had very weird issues, such as:

- If I put 1000ms timeout, it'll be called on 2 or 3 seconds.
- If I put 2000ms timeout or above, it'll never be called.

I'm using Android ICS and JB, and on both I get the issues above. Seems that timeout parameter is buggy.

As a workaround, I'm doing checks inside onload (example: if I'm downloading a file, I compare the checksum of local file, with the checksum of the same file on the server), and I'm simulating timeouts with JavaScript's setTimeout. It's working to an extend.

The code below demonstrate how to simulate a request timeout, with JS's setTimeout command:

```
var downloadDataReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
downloadDataReq.onload = function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    alert('loaded');
}
downloadDataReq.onerror = function(e) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    alert('error: ' + e.error);
}
var urlToDownloadData = 'http://10.1.1.183/maquina_local/arquivos/FirefoxPortable_12.0_PortugueseBR.paf.exe';
downloadDataReq.open("GET", urlToDownloadData);

var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    downloadDataReq.onload = function(){
        downloadDataReq.onerror({'error': 'timeout'});
    };
    downloadDataReq.abort();
}, 4000);

downloadDataReq.send();
```

On timeout, I'm changing onload event to onerror one, because if you try aborting a running request, it'll trigger 'onload' event, not 'onerror'. If you don't do it, this issue can give you corrupted files (ex: a 20mb file that, when request is aborted, file will be incomplete, with a size smaller than 20mb).

I'm still testing this solution, but at least for now, it solved a few bugs for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

Ti.App.timeOut = 99000;     //declare in app.js

then use anyWhere in your project.But make Sure every time when you create a httpClient.
dont recreate or redefine in Code or through out the page.
this works fine for me.

//HAVE A LOOK OVER THE USE OF THIS
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({timeout:Ti.App.timeOut});

Comment: I DOWNVOTED YOU that timeout is way too big. also, what if you want different timeouts (ie one for checking user input, another for some long-haul batch task)?